# How do I create two separate lists after stripping a line in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how I can take a file like this:

```
Bob
120
Joe
300
Jim
175
Jack
205
Jeffrey
155
Billy
135
```

and make it where I output a file with just the bowler's name and whether they received a perfect score, if they were above average or below average.
Here is the code that I have written but it will not work because I cannot split after the newline has been removed.

```
inputFile = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")
outputFile = open("bowlingaverages.txt", "w")

lines = inputFile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split(" ")
    Bowler = line[0]
    Score = line[1]
    def BowlingAverages(bowlingScore):
        average = 0
        if bowlingScore > 0:
            average += bowlingScore/ len(bowlingScore)
        return average
    outputFile.write(Bowler)
    if Score == 300:
        outputFile.write("perfect")
    elif Score > BowlingAverages(Score):
        outputFile.write("above average")
    else:
        outputFile.write("below average")

outputFile.close()
```

Comment: you can't measure the average before you have read the whole file.

Comment: so I need to do the average after I have used the for loop?

Comment: that would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = inputFile.readlines()
names = lines[0::2]
scores = lines[1::2]
```

If you want to strip/format the lines too, then replace the last two lines with

```
names = [name.strip() for name in lines[0::2]]
scores = [int(score) for score lines[1::2]]
```

If scores aren't all integers, you may want to replace `int` above with `float`.

Comment: okay that's familiar formatting for me but I just couldn't figure out how to strip the line and yet split it into two separate lists. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that your file has the order above

```
bowler_dict = dict()
for line in open(source.txt).readlines():
    try:
        score = int(line.strip())
        bowler_dict[current] = score
        current = None
    except ValueError:
        current = line.strip()
```

Now you have a dictionary

```
{'Jeffrey': 155, 'Jim': 175, 'Billy': 135, 'Joe': 300, 'Bob': 120, 'Jack': 205}
```

so lets figure out the average

```
>>> all_scores = bowler_dict.values()
>>> all_scores
[155, 175, 135, 300, 120, 205]
>>> average_score = sum(all_scores)/float(len(all_scores))
>>> average_score
181.66666666666666


>>> for bowler in bowler_dict:
        score =  bowler_dict[bowler]
        if score == 300:
            classify = 'PERFECT'

        if average_score < score < 300:
            classify = 'Above Average'
        else:
            classify = 'Below Average'
        print bowler, score, classify


Jeffrey 155 Below Average
Jim 175 Below Average
Billy 135 Below Average
Joe 300 Below Average
Bob 120 Below Average
Jack 205 Above Average
```

Comment: that will help me get the bowlers and averages into separate lists and allow me to output what I need?